# Change of color the word in each second, like in a karaoke

Tags: color

I have this text. I need that the first word to change to red in 1 second interval, then the second word, then the third word, until arrive the end of the text.

```
text = "Experiencie leads us to believe that the motions of physical 
        bodies are controlled by interactions between them and their 
        surroundings"
```

Comment: You seem to be asking someone just to do all your work for you. If you really have no clue, you should start smaller and learn the language in pieces. `StringSplit` and `Style` are good places to start.  Eventually you'll need `Dynamic`, which is a course in itself, as well as maybe `Refresh`/`UpdateInterval`. Of course there are a bunch of core language functions you'll need to put it all together.

Comment: I don't know what have you tried, but it's true that you didn't show any code (except the text) in your post, so it makes sense that someone assumes that you have not tried anything. It would be better if you show your existing code and explain where you're stuck at.

Comment: The "You seem" refers to the form of the question, which is just an expression of need, and how the question makes your intentions appear. Aside from the fact that you wrote the post, my remark is not meant to be personal, and certainly not a comment on your way of being. The form of the question itself shows no work other than providing an example text to process and seems to ask others, by expressing a need, to do all the rest of the work for you. In fact, I did not think it expressed your way of being -- it's not most people's way either, is it?

Comment: I work hard very day to learn Mathematica, but there times
code don' t work me.Ok I should have put my work.
My code was this : `Style[Pause[1]; #1, Red, Pause[2]; #2, Red] &["Hello", "here"]`

Answer (score 4):

```
ss = StringSplit[text];
Dynamic @ Row[MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, ss, {Clock[{1, Length@ss, 1}, Length@ss, 3]}], "  "]
```

[image]

Comment: This was what I really needed, thank you @kglr, your code was very useful and precise.

Comment: I need to exposure a work of the eye human, and with your code finally can do it. I modified your code (apologize for that), changed **Row** by Column, and  the number **3** for 1.

Comment: @Andres, glad it was useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way. Can be optimized more I suppose.

[image]

```
text = "Experiencie leads us to believe that the motions of physical 
          bodies are controlled by interactions between them and their 
          surroundings";

words = StringSplit[text];
i = 1;
Manipulate[
 ticks = Not[ticks];
 Pause[delay];
 colored = Table[If[n == i, Style[words[[n]], Red], words[[n]]], {n, 1, 
    Length@words}];
 i = Mod[i, Length@words];
 i++;
 Row[Riffle[colored, " "]],

 {{delay, 0.5, "delay"}, 0.1, 3, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ticks, True}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {ticks,delay}
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nasser.